# Struts2 validations annotation gives multiple messages

Tags: struts2, struts-validation, struts2-convention-plugin

I am using the convention plugin. Below is the @Validations annotation.

```
@Validations(
        requiredFields={@RequiredFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE, fieldName = "revenue", message = "You must enter a value for field.")},
         intRangeFields =
                { @IntRangeFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE, fieldName = "revenue", min = "1", max = "100", message = "id must be between 1 to 100.")},
         conversionErrorFields={@ConversionErrorFieldValidator(message="Not a valid Number", type= ValidatorType.SIMPLE, fieldName="id")}
        )
```

so when ever i am giving a character instead of number in the field to test. I am getting these 3 messages.

```
Invalid field value for field "id".
Not a valid Number
You must enter a value for field.
```

Instead i am expecting to get only the second or the first one. N from where i am getting the first error. As we can see that i have not given any such message. So how can i get only one appropriate message at a time.

Regards.

Comment: First is from the type conversion interceptor.

Comment: ok. So how to get only one message which is relevant

Comment: why not to do validations with the `validate()`?

Comment: The first error is a conversion error. Read the whole story: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23450365/1654265

Comment: This is very old ques I guess.

Comment: Definitely :| I didn't notice it was old... and I've no clue on how and from where I came here yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

Create new file in same package where your action class is defined,.”actionclassname.properties” and  in that file use this 
“invalid.fieldvalue.FieldName=give msg for user”.it is working also in my case it is working