# Change Struts Validator default messages

Tags: validation, struts2, struts, struts-validation

I am new in struts2 . I have created an XML file for validations, but when I test my form I don't get the error messages that I configured in the XML file. instead I get the Struts 2 defaults messages such as this one :

invalid field value for field "capteur.ENERGIE_CAPTEUR".

Is there anyway to make struts2 prints the messages configured in the XML file instead of the default ones ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a ***validation*** error message, it is a ***conversion*** error message.

You can override the default conversion error message up to each single object, by creating an entry for it in the global .properties file, as described in Struts 2 documentation, [Type Conversion Errors Handling](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-TypeConversionErrorHandling):

> By default, all conversion errors are reported using the generic i18n
>   key **xwork.default.invalid.fieldvalue**, which you can override (the
>   default text is ***Invalid field value for field "xxx"***, where xxx is the
>   field name) in your global i18n resource bundle.
>
> However, sometimes you may wish to override this message on a
>   per-field basis. You can do this by adding an i18n key associated with
>   just your action (Action.properties) using the pattern
>   **invalid.fieldvalue.xxx**, where xxx is the field name.

If you are interested in understanding how it works in a deeper way, read [the Short Story](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450365/1654265) about Validation, Conversion and Friends.