# How to call different method from execute in struts?

Tags: java, struts2

In my Struts app, I have an action, called Foo.

```
    <action name="Foo" class="some.path.here.foo">
        <result name="SUCCESS" type="tiles">/foo.tiles</result>
    </action>
```

Normally it calls execute(), but I want to call another method called change(). How can I do so?

My Idea was this:

```
    <form name="Foo" action="Foo" >
        <s:textfield name="Mail" placeholder="Mail" />
        <select name="someselect">
        <s:iterator value="someblabla">
            <option value="<s:property value="somevalue"/>" label="<s:property value="Description"/>"><s:property value="Name"/></option>
        </s:iterator>
        </select>
        <s:submit method="change" value="Go!"></s:submit>
    </form>
```

But when I want to do this, I get

```
HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action some.path.is.here.Foo and result input
```

Can you help me out here?

Comment: Are you using any kind of validation? When validation fails, it returns 'input' and there is not corresponding action defined for input.

Comment: Have you tried to follow advice given in the error log?

Comment: @AleksandrM I do not get anything else, then what I wrote up there.

Comment: Oh, dear. 1) "SUCCESS" must be "success". 2) method="something" in s:submit is DMI, and is deprecated, don't use it. 3) `No result defined for action some.path.is.here.Foo and result input` means something has gone wrong, and an INPUT result is returned, but you've not defined any "input" result in your struts.xml for that action. [Take a look at when and how this can happen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23450365/1654265).

Comment: @user4559929 What Exactly do you mean with validation? I will post my function in EDIT

Comment: *No result defined for action some.path.is.here.Foo and result input* - in other words *add the input result*. And java have **methods** not functions.

Comment: @user3383458
Just to verify my guess, try creating a page with some error message and add one more result action.
<result name="input">errorpage.html</result>

Comment: Check answer section

Comment: Unrelated, but there's rarely a great reason to make the option elements manually like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

execute is the default method in an action. If you want to change it i think you can modify the description of your action with adding the "method" attribute. Like that :

```
<action name="Foo" class="some.path.here.foo" method="change">
        <result name="SUCCESS" type="tiles">/foo.tiles</result>
</action>
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because, struts expects 'execute' method unless you specify explicitly. If your action method name is different, you have to specify it explicity using the parameter 'method'.

So your code should be

```
<action name="Foo" class="some.path.here.foo" method="change">
        <result name="SUCCESS" type="tiles">/foo.tiles</result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Struts 2 also supports wildcard methods and dynamic method invocation. DMI is less secure, and not preferred.  See the docs [here](http://struts.apache.org/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-WildcardMethod)