# SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: null java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, xml, validation, struts2, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create a basic Login/Registration in Struts2 in eclipse. I am getting exceptions that I am unable to solve, I am trying it for last few hours:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">

<struts>
    <include file="struts-default.xml"/>
    <package name="a" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="loginauth" class="com.project.loginreg.LoginAction" method="execute" >
           <result name="SUCCESS" type="redirect">
        <param name="location">/welcome.jsp</param>
        </result>
            <result name="ERROR">/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Login_Reg</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>
       org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter                
</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is the problem details I am geting

```
Sep 17, 2015 4:54:41 PM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DefaultDispatcherErrorHandler error
SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.project.loginreg.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:870)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1293)
    at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:117)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:108)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1369)
    at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:458)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$2.execute(OgnlUtil.java:309)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecute(OgnlUtil.java:340)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.getValue(OgnlUtil.java:307)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:423)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:287)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:250)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:76)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:125)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:253)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Heres the LoginAction:

```
package com.project.loginreg;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String userId;
    private String password;

    private Boolean error;

    public String execute(){
        if (userId.equals("")) {
            addActionError("Please Enter user id.");
            error = true;
        }
        else if(password.equals("")){
            addActionError("Please Enter Password.");
            error = true;
        }
         else if(!userId.equalsIgnoreCase(password)) {
             addActionError("Invalid userid or password.");
             error = true;
         } else {
             error = false;
         }
        if (error) {
            return ERROR;
        } else {
            return SUCCESS;
        }   
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the LoginAction.java and what's on the line#14?

Comment: @KarthikR posted it.. Please check and help me

Comment: Please post your JSP as well. The userId you are mapping is not being received.

Comment: Your NPE is coz of your null userName. This can be avoided by initializing but that's not your problem I suppose

Comment: @KarthikR  
After doing as u said,that exception has been removed but I am getting another one.... –  Sourav 48 secs ago   edit   
     
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher warn WARNING: Could not find action or result: /Login_Reg/loginAuth.action There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [loginAuth] associated with context path [/Login_Reg]. - [unknown location]

Comment: `/Login_Reg/loginauth.action` . Should it be a lower case?

Comment: @KarthikR Yes ... I mean "Login_Reg" as project name..  and then action mapping "loginauth.action"

Comment: @KarthikR No result defined for action com.project.loginreg.LoginAction and result error- what may be the reason for this prob?

Comment: `I am trying it for last few years` duude, you really need some help then :|

Comment: @AndreaLigios omg!! :D lolz...  sorry , I wanted to write Hours.

Comment: What you should know about nullpointerexception, it tells you that you have something wrong in the code or data supplied into it that doesn't work and if you prevent it in the code using some techniques then it will not throw the exception but the program does not become working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
private String userId
```

is not initialized. It's NULL.
If you want to match against an empty string you'd have to initialize it first.

so change it to

```
private String userId = "";
```

Comment: After doing as u said,that exception has been removed but I am getting another one....

Comment: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher warn
WARNING: Could not find action or result: /Login_Reg/loginAuth.action
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [loginAuth] associated with context path [/Login_Reg]. - [unknown location]

Answer (score 2):

You are in deep water... :| By the way, in a nutshell:

> #### Preventing NPE

To prevent NPE when comparing strings, compare them with the known one:

```
if (userId.equals("")) { // throws NPE
if ("".equals(userId)) { // it's ok
```

In your code however you should check also null, so both are ok:

```
if (userId==null || userId.equals("")) {
```

> #### The right place for this: Validation

Now that they work, remove all this checks and put them [in the `validate()` method, or in a **validation.xml** file](https://struts.apache.org/docs/form-validation-using-xml.html), or use **annotations** for validating them. Struts supports all of this methods, and [returns the `INPUT` result when things go south](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450365/1654265).

Never put this kind of checks in an action method, it's the wrong place.

> #### The right Struts2 way to handle authentication: Interceptor

Don't use actions to do this, but create an Authentication Interceptor, applying it to all the actions except the login/logout ones.

There is a [full working example here](http://www.journaldev.com/2210/struts-2-interceptor-tutorial-with-custom-authentication-interceptor-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your private variable `userId` is not initialized.  This comment is correct.
However, you should write a set function

```
public void setUserId(String userId){
    this.userId =userId;
}
```

to initialize your variable instead of

```
private String userId = "";
```

I have the same problem as yours and this my solution.