# Struts2 custom interceptos not calling when validation errors coming from validation xml file?

Tags: validation, struts2, struts-validation, struts2-interceptors, interceptorstack

I wrote an interceptor for struts2 application and configured in struts configuration file. Here i am using this interceptor for only some actions , not for globally.So here my problem is when validation errors are coming from ActionName-validation.xml at that time my custom interceptor is not working.Please give me suggestion/solution.

Comment: BTW next time consider posting some code, even if the question is clear

Answer (score 1):

First of all, read [how the validation (and conversion) error are handled by Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450365/1654265), then move your Interceptor BEFORE the Validation/Parameters/ConversionError Interceptors

The easier way is to define a new stack with your interceptor at first (or in the middle, "exploding" the defaultStack) like follows:

```xml
<interceptor-stack name="customStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="customInterceptor"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
</interceptor-stack>
```

And then apply `customStack` or `defaultStack` action by action or package by package, according to your needs.

Comment: Did it work ? If no, just feed back here, if yes, please remember to accept and upvote the answer, thank you