# Struts is taking incorrect return string. Instead of "input" it should take "success"

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts2-interceptors, interceptorstack

I am developing an application using struts 2 and hibernate. I have a submit button on my jsp page which is having action **`EvaluateRating`**

**JSP Page**

```xml
<s:form action="EvaluateRating">
//  Some jsp code here //
    <s:hidden name="Year" value="2015" />
    <s:submit value="Evaluate" cssStyle="float:right"/>
</s:form>
```

and this action is mapped in **`struts.xml`**

**struts.xml**

```xml
<action name="EvaluateRating" class="Action.RatingAction" method="EvaluateRating">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="Year">${Year}</param>
        <param name="actionName">MgrPage</param>
    </result>
    <result name="input">/Index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

My `EvaluateRating()` method looks like:

**RatingAction.java**

```java
public String EvaluateRating() {
    this.setYear(this.getYear());
    return "success";
}
```

Issue that I am facing is I have returned **`success`** from the method, but still it is taking **`input`** as a return string and redirecting to **`Index.jsp`** page. Instead it should take **`success`** and redirect to the action **`MgrPage`**.

And If I don't write **`<result name="input">/Index.jsp</result>`** line in my **struts.xml**. It is giving me following error:

> Struts Problem Report
>
> Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
>
> Messages: No result defined for action Action.RatingAction and result input

```xml
Stacktraces
No result defined for action Action.RatingAction and result input 
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its seems some interceptor applying before that action and its return input as a result.

Check and remove interceptor on this action.

Comment: I have not written any interceptor code in that action. You can see my **`struts.xml`** code above.

Comment: +1 For understanding that it is an interceptor returning the INPUT result. -1 for suggesting to remove the interceptor instead of fixing the problem.

Comment: @Andrea i suggest to remove unnecessary custom interceptor which create problem.

Comment: Exactly. That's an error. The interceptor is not CAUSING the problem, it's just bringing it to your attention. If you have a fire burning your kitchen, and the fire alarm is screaming, your solution is to turn off the fire alarm ?

Comment: agree with your concern. i mean to say if custom interceptor cause problem than look into it and come to solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I have not written any interceptor code in that action. You can see my struts.xml code above.

If you don't specify any interceptor for an action, you are using the default interceptor stack defined for your package.

If you've not changed the default interceptor stack for your package, you are using the default one, that is called [**defaultStack**](https://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-defaultxml.html):

```xml
<interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="datetime"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="deprecation"/>
</interceptor-stack>
```

An Interceptor Stack is a list of interceptor that filter the request from the page to the action, and after the action execution to the page

[image]

You must always define (locally to the action, or globally to the package) an INPUT result, to avoid getting

> Messages: No result defined for action Action.RatingAction and result input

Why and when the INPUT result is returned from Interceptors ? There are different causes: validation errors, conversion errors, etc..

Ensure to read carefully

> [Struts2 INPUT result: how does it work? How are conversion / validation errors handled?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450365/1654265)

---

To see which is the error, you can map the `input` result to the same page you are coming from, and (if using the XHTML default theme), the error will appear next to the field generating it (presumably `Year`, since it's the only one). If instead you want to print it in other pages like `index.jsp`, you can loop through the `fieldErrors` that you will get by making your action extend ActionSupport.

---

That said, you're using wrong naming (Year must be year, never start with a uppercase letter in OGNL (struts tags) and configuration (struts.xml), so start by correcting that, and also remove the     `this.setYear(this.getYear());` that is completely useless.

Comment: Have you tried ? Please don't forget to accept and upvote the answer, thank you