# Getting object related to the selected value in a struts s:select dropdown

Tags: jsp, drop-down-menu, struts2

I have this dropdown in the JSP:

```xml
<s:select name = "destination"
         label = "the destination" 
          list = "drop" 
     listValue = "nameDest" 
     headerKey = "0" 
   headerValue = "chose a destination" />
```

and there is the `destination` object in the action class:

```java
private Destination destination;
//getters and setters
```

but when I submit, I get this error:

> No result defined for action `com.iticsys.GBO.actions.UserAction` and result `input`

When I removed the dropdown, everything worked fine. So I think that Struts is trying to put the value of the selected value from `nameDest`, which is a string, into the `destination` object in the action class.

So how could I get the selected object?

UPDATE :

destination is an object instanced from Destination class :

```
@Entity
public class Destination {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idDest;
private String nameDest;
```

drop is a list of Destination :

```
private List<Destination> drop;
public List<Destination> getDrop() {
    return drop;
}
public void setDrop(List<Destination> drop) {
    this.drop = drop;
}
```

After some modification (suggested by Andrea Ligios ) on the drop down:

```xml
        <tr>
            <td>
                <s:select 
                name="destination.idDest"
                label="the destination" 
                list="drop" 
                listKey="idDest"
                listValue="nameDest" 
                headerKey="0" 
                headerValue="Chose a destination" />
           </td>
        </tr>
```

I got this error

> 1.tag 'select', field 'list', name 'destination.idDest': The requested list key 'drop' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name}

Comment: What is the `Destination` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're sending a `String` to a `Destination` variable, the types don't match and hence the interceptor stack is raising the error and changing the workflow from the normal execution of the action method you've called, to the `INPUT` result defined for your action.

Since you've not defined any `INPUT` result, it raises the error message you're seeing.

Read [how the INPUT result works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450365/1654265) (the pattern is common both to conversion *and* validation).

Then you need

1. to define an INPUT result
2. to specify in your select the `listKey`
3. to specify in your select the `name` attribute including the key.

If, for example, Destination has `id` and `nameDest` fields, you need to set:

```xml
<s:select name = "destination.id"
         label = "the destination" 
          list = "drop" 
       listKey = "id" 
     listValue = "nameDest" 
     headerKey = "0" 
   headerValue = "chose a destination" />
```

Comment: I made the modifications you suggested and now I got this error,

1.tag 'select', field 'list', name 'destination.idDest': The requested list key 'drop' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name}.                                                                                                
AND I want to add that the drop list is a list<Destination>

Comment: You must've changed something else, because you had `drop` before and it should have given you this error message back then. Feel free to post your source list definition and getter, and the pojo content to get more help

Comment: Everything is fine. Please add also the new select code, the one adapted from my answer... the problem is most likely there

Comment: Are you using ModelDriven ?

Comment: I restarted eclipse, and now it's working, I don't know why.