# Struts2 action with parameter is not working

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, http, struts2

I am calling struts2 action from jQuery with parameter but action method is not called.

But If I called the action without parameter then its working perfectly.

Calling action :

> `$('#redemptionForm').attr('action','sendRedempOTP?pbCardNo='+cardNo+'&mobile='+mobileNumber+'&isSearchByMobileNoFlag='+searchByMobileNoFlag);`

Struts2 action Details:

```xml
<action name="sendRedempOTP" class="com.ndil.web.redemption.ViewGiftItemSlabsAction" 
      method="sendOTP">
            <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
            <result name="error">/jsp/balanceinquirymain2.jsp</result>
            <result>/jsp/balanceinquirymain2.jsp</result>       
</action>
```

Action Class method :

```
public String sendOTP() {   
        LOGGER.info("Send OTP called");

        String cardNumber = request.getParameter("pbCardNo");
        String mobile = request.getParameter("mobile");
        String isSearchByMobileNoFlag = request.getParameter("isSearchByMobileNoFlag");
}
```

When I am calling this action then its not working. 
I am getting below exception :

```
No configuration found for the specified action: 'login' in namespace:
```

What is wrong with this code?

My JSP Page:

```xml
<s:form action="#" validate="true" method="post" id="redemptionForm">

        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table width="950" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" style="background-color: #999">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-color: #f1f1f1">
                                <table width="950" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                                    <tr align="center">
                                        <td class="fieldtxt" width="50%" align="right"><s:text name="redeem.cardNo" /></td>
                                        <td width="50%" align="left"><s:property value="giftRedemptionVO.pbCardNo" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr align="center">
                                        <td class="fieldtxt" width="50%" align="right"><s:text name="redeem.mobileNo" /></td>
                                        <td width="50%" align="left"><s:property value="giftRedemptionVO.mobileNo" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr id="custNameRow" align="center">
                                        <td class="fieldtxt" width="50%" align="right"><s:text name="redeem.total.available.shopping.value" /></td>
                                        <td width="50%" align="left"><s:property value="giftRedemptionVO.totalAvailableAmount" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <td><s:submit value="Redeem(SendOTP)" cssClass="crt_btn" id="sendOtpButton" theme="simple"
                </td>
            </tr>   
        </table>
</s:form>
```

Comment: please post your jsp code.

Comment: i can't see your Jquery code.

Comment: I have mentioned above how I called my action from JSP page.

Comment: use $('#redemptionForm').attr('action','sendRedempOTP?pbCardNo='+cardNo.value()+'&mobile='+mobileNumber.value()+'&isSearchByMobileNoFlag='+searchByMobileNoFlag.value());

Comment: Why the configuration of `login` action is logged?

Answer (score 0):

Strust2 is not use this way to get parameter.
you can try this way:

```
 public void execute() {  
     String name = super.getRequest().getParameter("pbCardNo");  
     System.out.println("name：" + name);  
 }
```

or you can try this way:

```
private String pbCardNo；
public void setPbCardNod(String pbCardNo){}
public String getPbCardNod(){}
```

maybe that way can help you

Comment: I saw you hava use giftRedemptionVO this entity, maybe you should add that code: private GiftRedemptionVO giftRedemptionVO; and the getter and setter method. it will injection into this entity and then you can use it to get the parameter what you want

Comment: public void execute() ?

Comment: it's just an example

Comment: Yes, but since `execute()` is the default Struts2 method, and Struts2 methods always return Strings, it is misleading to write `public void execute()`. Just edit the example and return SUCCESS, instead of defending an incorrect code

Answer (score 0):

1. When sending a form with `POST`, the data in the form is already serialized, there's no need to encode the values as QueryString parameters like in a GET;
2. Always use private attributes with **getters** and **setters** to receive / expose data, you almost never need to read from the request;
3. You've probably a global `INPUT` result mapped to the `login` action, and it is being triggered. If it is like that, is wrong for many reasons:

   - the `login` action doesn't exist
   - the `login` action should be triggered only for credential problems, not for every INPUT result
   - if the INPUT result is triggered, however, it means that you're sending something wrong to the page, so the parameters need to be checked carefully. [Read more on the INPUT result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450365/1654265)

Answer (score 0):

Why you are sending with url.
If you are able to get into javascript.
Create

```
<s:hiddent id="test" name="test"/>

$('#test').value("your value");

String test;

setTest
getTest

String cardNumber = getTest();
```