# Method calling inside setter is prefered or not in struts 2

Tags: java, validation, struts2, getter-setter, struts-validation

I am creating Setter and Getter in action class, and calling a method in each setter for server side validation.

I am calling methods for validating mobile number and so on.. my question to all is:

is it prefered to call those methods inside the action class, instead that from the setters ?

Answer (score 0):

> Method calling inside setter is prefered ? [...] Is it prefered to call inside action class ?

None of the above.

First of all, you should **avoid putting *any* kind of logic** inside Getters and Setters;

On top of that, for the specific case of Validation, Struts2 provides several ways to do it properly, through the framework:

1) [`validate()` method](http://struts.apache.org/docs/form-validation.html)

2) [XML validation](http://struts.apache.org/docs/validation.html)

3) Annotations validation

Start with n.1, when it work, eventually try one of the others.

It is important to let the framework validate your inputs in the right places and moments (across the interceptor stack), [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450365/1654265) to understand why.